# Where is template_preprocess() located

Tags: files

where is the `template_preprocess()` function located? It seems that my `markaspot` theme (`mas`) call this function but I can not find this funktion in a file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in

```
includes/theme.inc.
```

[Docs are here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/7).

Next time just put the name of the function in Google...the docs on Drupal.org will tell you what file any function is in.

Comment: You beat me and clicked "post" faster. Again. :D And for search, if someone knows the exact name of a function, search box located on the right of https://api.drupal.org may be faster and more accurate than Google, in my experience.

Comment: Yep good point about the search on d.o, that's a better idea than google :)